# How can I count array elements in Postman tests

Tags: arrays, api, postman-testcase

I have a json response like this and I would like to count how many Friend Groups are in MyFriends array (in my case I expect the code to return 7) :
[image]

I tried following but it throws tis error--

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

```
var data = pm.response.json().MyFriends[0].FriendGroupProperties;

pm.test('Number of friends = ' + MyFriends.length, function () {
    pm.expect(data.length).to.equal(7);
});
```

I also tried this but it also throws

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

error :

```
var data = pm.response.json().MyFriends;

var count = Object.keys(data).length;

console.log("The number of expected friends in the response body is: " + count);

console.log(`Number of Friends: ${_.size(data)}`)
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is array data (start `[` and end `]`) in your body.

It has single item of array, and `MyFriends` is first field , then it has 7 items of array.

You can add console log(print) step by step as I added in my code.

Also console output(left bottom side of UI) help to debug and can get the correct data position and length as I attached image.

Using this test code

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData.length)
console.log(jsonData[0])
console.log(jsonData[0].MyFriends)
console.log(jsonData[0].MyFriends.length)

pm.test('Number of friends = ' + jsonData[0].MyFriends.length, function () {
    pm.expect(jsonData[0].MyFriends.length).to.equal(7);
});
```

It is screen of Postman
[image]

Test Result
[image]

This is online console
[image]